# Closing the New Window on a new Thread (WPF)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading

Hi I had posted a question along these lines recently but this is now a little more specific to my requirements. So, I have an Application where the user needs to log in. The log in process can take some time so I decided to put up a little animated GIF to show it is doing something. Sounds simple...!!??

I noticed soon that the login process was freezing the animation so I thought, I will put the login process on its own thread. I had countless instances of it referencing objects on the UI Thread so thought I would try the other way round and have the Image display on a new thread. Same issue - so I decided to create a new window containing the image, format it accordingly and display this as a new thread! Simple! That (bit) worked... I click to login, animation appears and disappears onces login is complete. So the Thread variable is set as global one:

```
Friend g_thLoading As Thread
```

And when the Login button is clicked I have the following:

```
    g_thLoading = New Thread(AddressOf LoginSplashScreen)
    g_thLoading.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    g_thLoading.IsBackground = True
    g_thLoading.Name = "LoginThread"
    g_thLoading.Start()


    VerifyLogin()          'Process that takes a while...


    g_thLoading.Abort()
```

Then the method that is called in the new thread:

```
Sub LoginSplashScreen()

    Dim SplashScreenWin As New SplashScreen()

    Try
        SplashScreenWin.ShowDialog()
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
    Catch ex As Exception
        SplashScreenWin.Close()
        SplashScreenWin = Nothing
    End Try

End Sub
```

This works - but not if I have to click the button more than once. However If (for example) the user enters the wrong credentials, clicks login (the above processes and completes) they are prompted to re-enter - click the login button again... but this time, the window doesnt display (but oddly does appear in the Task Bar)... Then the application is forced to close (nothing in debug on why that is).

I am confident that the Dialogue Window is closing correctly after the first instance as i) it is no longer in the Task Bar and secondly I have put some checks on the Windows Close event. I am fairly confident that the created Thread is closed after the first instance as I can see it drop off from the Thread Window in Visual Studio... So - I am at a total loss. I have also tried the Join function on the thread but this just hangs the process before it gets to g_thLoading.Abort()

I am open to any advice on how I can go about achieving my end goal... whether it is expanding on what I have done here or another suggestion altogether. I have messed around with the Background Worker but not had much more luck there.

Comment: I might add that I needed to put this new window on a new thread as the login process would halt until the new window was closed... I cant help but think that there must be a much easier solution to my problem!?

Comment: The UI thread shouldn't be used for time consuming actions.  Put the login process in a background thread, or put it into a `BackgroundWorker`, which does the same thing. The UI thread still has to wait for the login to finish, but the program will remain responsive to the user while the login occurs.

Comment: I had tried that first, but I was having problems with objects being on the UI Thread that are referenced by the new 'Heavy Load' thread. I attempted to pass over the values I needed from the UI thread as parameters but I was having problems using those parameters when creating a new instance of an object... Further Still - the object being created needs to (after the login process) be available to the UI thread.

Comment: The `BackgroundWorker` is specifically designed to do what you want it to do. I'm going to add an answer as there isn't enough space in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `BackgroundWorker` class to implement your long running processes.  The class allows you to specify code that will run on a background thread (in the `DoWork` event handler), code that will run during "updates" on the thread that created the `BackgroundWorker` in the `ProgressChanged` event handler, and code that will run when the process completes, again on the thread that created the `BackgroundWorker` in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

Using it goes something like this:

```
private class LoginParameters {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    // Any other properties needed
}

// Make this a property of your form.
BackgroundWorker LoginWorker { get; set; }

// Somewhere in your UI code after the user clicks the "login button"
LoginWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
LoginWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
LoginWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true; // Can set to false if you don't allow the operation to be cancelled.
LoginWorker.DoWorker += DoLogin;
LoginWorker.ProgressChanged += ReportProgress;
LoginWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += LoginFinished;

LoginParameters login = new LoginParameters {
    // Code to initialize everything here
};

LoginWorker.RunWorkerAsync(login);

// Put this in the click event handler for the Cancel button, if you have one
if ( LoginWorker != null )
    LoginWorker.CancelAsync();

private void DoLogin(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker) sender; 
    LoginParameters login = (LoginParameters) e.Argument;

    // Your logic to process the login goes here. It should periodically do the following to check to see if the user clicked the cancel button:
    if ( worker.CancellationPending ) {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }

    // When you want to update the UI, do this:
    worker.ReportProgress( percentComplete, objectWithOtherDataToWriteToTheUI );

    // When you're done, just return.
}

private void ReportProgress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    // Your code to extract the data you need to update the display from the arguments & to then update the display goes here.  Remember, this runs on the UI thread
    }

private void LoginFinished( object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e ) {
    if (e.Cancelled == true)
        // Your code to inform the user of the cancellation here
    else if (e.Error != null)
        // All unhadgled exceptions throws by the DoWork event handler end up here
        // Your code to inform the user of the error here
    else {
        // Your code to inform the user of the success goes here.
        // Remember, this runs on the UI thread.

        // I recommend you set the form BackgroundWorker property to null after its finished, as you can't reuse it after its finished. 
        LoginWorker = null;
    }
}
```

Sorry this is in C# if you're looking for VB.NET, but it shouldn't be hard to translate.